# Azure Mobile Apps - Entity Framework - Foreign Key and other Attributes missing

Tags: entity-framework, azure, foreign-keys, azure-mobile-services

In Azure Mobile Apps I'm trying to add a foreign key attribute to my DataObject class.

It seems like any attribute is not recognized, and I get an error msg..

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace SomeNameSpace.DataObjects
{
     [ForeignKey("examplekeyname")]
     public string SomeDataColmnName {get; set;}
```

I have done this before so I'm confused as to what is causing this.

Went through several Azure Mobile Apps Tutorials again but doesn't seem to be working.

I get the following error msg:

> Error CS0246
>   The type or namespace name 'ForeignKeyAttribute' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

It's not just foreign key.. other attributes show the same behavior... like `[Required]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those attributes are in the assembly System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations. See [ForeignKeyAttribute Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.foreignkeyattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: Thanks Donna, again.  Seems like i had to 1) Add System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations as a reference to the project, and 2) add using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;